# C# Opening an Excel work sheet file from FileStream

Tags: c#, excel

I need to open an existing worksheet and using OPENXML tools, modify it, but I don't seem to have the opening down

```
 // Append a new worksheet and associate it with the workbook.
   XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
   doc.Load(new FileStream(sheetfilename + ".xls", FileMode.Open));
   Sheet sheet;
   //?
```

Problem with the above is how to take the XML and open it as a Sheet.

Below is another attempt I made earlier to do something similar using a FileStream but I got the error

```
Cannot convert type System.IO.FileStream to Document.OpenXML.SpreadSheet.Sheet

Sheet sheet = (Sheet)new FileStream(sheetfilename + ".xls",FileMode.Open);
```

Can I please get some help with this please?

Comment: xls is not an OpenXML format, needs to be xlsx (2007 or above)

Comment: Oh! But how do I convert one of those to the current format please? Is there a way to do this in code since I am able to open the .xls file in Excel 2010.

Comment: I recommend u to use ADO.NET to Open, it's easy and you can open both xsl and xslx..., I do not have used OpenXML yet so I don't known if u can create a new document, if u can, so open older with ado, save new with openxml

Answer (score 0):

If it's an older, non-OpenXML version of version of Excel you can use NPOI, it's available for download here:

http://npoi.codeplex.com/

```
HSSFWorkbook workbook;

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(sheetfilename + ".xls", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);

    var sheet = workbook.GetSheet("Sheet1");

    ...do something..
}
```

Comment: I get an exception when I try the above --- Invalid header signature; read 0x0010000000080809, expected 0xE11AB1A1E011CFD0